# Execute Script when leaving a window

Tags: macos, shell-script, applescript

is it possible to execute a Script (Applescript/Shellscript) when I leave a window (and when I switch back to it)?
What I want to do: I want to pause my VM when I leave the VM-Window (vmrun pause path/to/vm) and I want to resume the VM when I switch back to the VM (vmrum unpause path/to/vm).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save something like this as stay open application in AppleSript Editor.

```
set prev to false
repeat
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        try
            tell process "TextEdit"
                set now to frontmost and name of window 1 is "Test.txt"
            end tell
        on error
            set now to false
        end try
        if prev and not now then say "the window was unfocused"
        set prev to now
    end tell
end repeat
```

If you don't want to run a background process, you could just store `prev` in a file and run the script with a LaunchAgent every few seconds.